# Thunderbird: different tag colors only for new email

Tags: thunderbird, colors

I have set up custom `tags` in Thunderbird, and corresponding filters, so that email arriving in my inbox is filtered based on sender, and tagged with corresponding `tag`. In my inbox, this than appears as differently colored emails. So far so good.

This works nicely, but I have realized that I don't actually want to have differently colored emails in my inbox. **I would like the tag color to have effect only for new (unread) email.** Once the email has been read, it should not be colored differently.

Let's say, currently I have `red` and `blue` tags.

Normally, new emails are in bold font. Normal emails are bold white, emails tagged with `red` are bold red, and so on. After I have read email (ie, clicked on it), the bold disappears.

I would like the tag color to disappear as well.

So that, in effect, all new emails are bold (same as now), and only new emails are actually colored differently, based on tag. So, all emails that are read, should all look the same.

I know how to make all new emails bold red:

```
#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(unread), treechildren::-moz-tree-cell- 
text(hasUnreadMessages-true) {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

I also know how to change the color of a given tag:

```
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(Tred, selected) {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(Tred, selected) {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

but I don't know how to achieve what I have described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping someone would come up with a better solution based on CSS or something, and maybe they still will, but until then here's a kludge using a message filter. The downside is that it'll have an unavoidable update delay of up to a minute after a message is read for the colors to update.

First, a "Read" tag is needed that's of higher priority than all other tags to be used. The reason: tags are hierarchical; if a message is assigned more than one tag, only the highest priority tag's color is displayed. Ideally, tag 1 (the default "Important" tag) would be the "Read" tag.

Next, a filter with the "Periodically" option selected, like that shown below, is needed (where the "Important" tag shown would be the whatever tag is selected to be the "Read" tag):

[image: Filter Rules dialog box for Read Messages filter]

Then, to reduce the period for running the filter:

1. Open Thunderbird's Config Editor
2. type `periodic` into the search box
3. double click on `mail.server.default.periodicFilterRateMinutes`, and
4. change the value to `1` (and hit `OK`, of course). If you return to your "Read Messages" filter, it should now say "Periodically, every minute" rather than "Periodically, every 10 minutes".

When the filter runs, the "Read" messages should be tagged with the higher priority "Read" tag, thereby overriding the coloring set by the messages' other tags, changing their coloring to that of the "Read" tag.

Full disclosure: I tested it all *except* letting it run periodically, instead only running the filter manually. Didn't want to accidentally set tags on all of my read messages.

Please... Someone... Come up with a better solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like the property `unread` that you used, there also exists `read`.

You could perhaps add an additional filter for `read` in order to reverse the color change.

I can't try it, so the following is just a guess:

```
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(read)
{
    font-weight:normal !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: If the `read` property works, then there might be another way of making rules that work.

Comment: The add-on [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) adds more options for filters, including a "Remove Tag" action.

Comment: See also [How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)